# Why is my Alchemical Bag not opening?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Whenever I attempt to open the Alchemical Bag it won't open. I've re-installed the game and Googled for similar issues but haven't found anything. I used NEI to acquire it while my wife said she acquired it without cheats and she wasn't able to use it either. I want to think it's because I haven't met a certain requirement yet.

Why is the Alchemical Bag not opening? Any knowledge on what is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of Equivalent Exchange in FTB is a prerelease version of EE3, which does not feature (and might never) the Alchemical Bag as we know it from EE2.

The Alchemical Bag is still present in the code for the preview releases of EE3, but only as a holdover from EE2. It has no code to make it do anything, no recipe to craft it, and is only possible to get (useless though it is) through NEI.

Comment: do you have a link for all the items that aren't currently present in the current version of FTB for EE?

Comment: It's easier to list the things in EE3 that are similar than the huge list of things not present. Almost nothing remains, since it's a ground-up rewrite. The Minium Stone is the only real feature of EE3 so far, which serves as a kind of Philosopher's Stone that takes damage.

Comment: AFAIK, the only item from EE3 currently obtainable in survival legitimately is the Minium Stone. The Philosopher's Stone exists in the code but the only feature of it at this point is that it has more durability than the Minium Stone.